# Como incluir o cabeçalho Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Tags: html-meta-tag

estou em um pequeno projeto com php e recebo um video em qual a origem é uma câmera IP e necessito tirar uma foto de um quadro do video e converte-la em base64 para salvar no banco de dados, ocorre que não consigo usar a tag video pra receber o video da camera IP ,pois o navegador reclama da ausência do cabeçalho Access-Control-Allow-Origin , como escrever este cabeçalho no html? ja tentei  e nada...

Comment: Qual é a linguagem que tens no servidor?

Comment: Apenas PHP, usando o xampp

Comment: Ok, já testaste colocar no PHP `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` como indicado na resposta em baixo?

Comment: Sim sérgio, foi feito mas não funcionou,a mensagem continua do mesmo jeito.Estou tentando de outra maneira. Ficaria mais fácil se eu utiliza-se a tag video, mas como o src é uma cam IP, não consigo pois da esse problema.

Comment: José, só para esclarecer caso tenha sido você que negativou as respostas abaixo que indicam o uso do cabeçalho via head(), não é porque não funcionou com você que você deve negativar as respostas. Não funciona assim, você tem a oportunidade de comentar abaixo dizendo que não funcionou para que a pessoa possa buscar novas soluções para você.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

José,

Não sei se é do seu conhecimento, mas isso algo do lado servidor, que no seu caso é PHP. Ou seja, não será no HTML que você irá corrigir, mas no PHP. Isso é uma questão relacionada ao [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) ou Cross-origin resource sharing. Dê uma lida no link que deixei.

Dando a minha explicação para lhe ajudar na compreensão, uma aplicação web pode carregar livremente imagens, stylesheets, scripts, iframes, videos e plugins como o Adobe Flash de qualquer domínio. Porém, web fonts e requisições em Ajax são limitadas apenas para dentro do próprio domínio, e no seu caso, provavelmente de um domínio X você está fazendo uma requisição Ajax para o domínio Y ou carregando a fonte de um domínio Z.

Isso ocorreu uma vez comigo quando de uma aplicação web, que estava em um domínio(http://localhost:8080/minhaaplicacao/), eu realizei uma requisição Ajax em um web service, que estava em domínio diferente(http://localhost:8080/meuwebservice/).

Eu resolvi adicionando apenas no cabeçalho do meu web service a permissão para esse tipo de requisição. No meu caso era Java, mas como você está fazendo uso do PHP, a solução será adicionar a seguinte linha de código:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

No código acima, estamos liberando para requisições de todo e qualquer domínio, pois, como é comum no nosso mundo, `*` indica algo como *ALL*. Caso você queira especificar quais domínios específicos poderão fazer a requisição, basta substituir o `*` pelo endereço dessa forma:

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://meusite.com', false);
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://outrosite.com', false);
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.maisum.com', false);
```

Espero ter ajudado em algo, qualquer coisa deixe um comentário!

Comment: Gostaria de entender o motivo de terem me negativado. Exponha o porquê, por favor...

Comment: Não fui que o negativo Younger Aud , agradeço a todos  que tentaram me ajudar.Resolvi o problema com um software de terceiros.

Answer (score 0):

à algum tempo tive este mesmo problema , porem o cabeçalho `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` tem que ser adicionado ao server-side.

Adicione ao seu servidor:

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://site1.com');
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://exemplo.com');
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.site2.com');
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.site3.com');
```

Ou se quiser habilitar todos use:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso não tem como fazer.

O cabeçalho não deve ir na sua página, e sim no que está tentando ser acessada remotamente, no caso ele teria que ser adicionado na câmera IP, o que provavelmente é impossível.

Nestes casos geralmente o que se faz para contornar o problema é fazer a requisição do lado do servidor, geralmente se cria tipo um "proxy", onde sua página usa javascript para fazer a requisição ao seu próprio site, e então você faz a requisição por PHP por exemplo ao recurso externo, no caso a câmera, porém como neste caso ele é um vídeo eu não sei como isso se comportaria.

Comment: O problema aqui é que eu consigo capturar um video em um iframe, e com javascr4ipt eu consigo tirar uma foto do iframe e desenha-la em um canvas, até aí tudo certo, o passo seguinte seria eu converter o desenho no canvas para base64, porém toda vez que eu faço isso o resultado é uma imagem em branco, pelo que vi se eu usa-se a tag <video> eu conseguiria tirar uma foto de um frame , mas como estou usando a tag <iframe> não esta rolando.Obrigado pela ajuda.